# What is the best way to cache single object within fixed timeout?

Tags: java, guava

Google Guava has CacheBuilder that allows to create ConcurrentHash with expiring keys that allow to remove entries after the fixed tiemout. However I need to cache only one instance of certain type.

What is the best way to cache single object within fixed timeout using Google Guava?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I'd use Guava's [Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(Supplier delegate, long duration, TimeUnit unit)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoizeWithExpiration(com.google.common.base.Supplier,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

```
public class JdkVersionService {

    @Inject
    private JdkVersionWebService jdkVersionWebService;

    // No need to check too often. Once a year will be good :) 
    private final Supplier<JdkVersion> latestJdkVersionCache
            = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(jdkVersionSupplier(), 365, TimeUnit.DAYS);


    public JdkVersion getLatestJdkVersion() {
        return latestJdkVersionCache.get();
    }

    private Supplier<JdkVersion> jdkVersionSupplier() {
        return new Supplier<JdkVersion>() {
            public JdkVersion get() {
                return jdkVersionWebService.checkLatestJdkVersion();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

## Update with JDK 8

Today, I would write this code differently, using JDK 8 method references and constructor injection for cleaner code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.google.common.base.Suppliers;

@Service
public class JdkVersionService {

    private final Supplier<JdkVersion> latestJdkVersionCache;

    @Inject
    public JdkVersionService(JdkVersionWebService jdkVersionWebService) {
        this.latestJdkVersionCache = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(
                jdkVersionWebService::checkLatestJdkVersion,
                365, TimeUnit.DAYS
        );
    }

    public JdkVersion getLatestJdkVersion() {
        return latestJdkVersionCache.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know a solution for the case when the supplier is throwing a checked exception?

Comment: @user2417480 I would probably wrap that exception in a RuntimeException. Maybe unwrap it later if you really want to keep a checked exception, but it's usually an anti-pattern to carry around a checked exception across multiple layers... That's why e.g. spring-jdbc has a translation layer to convert checked exceptions into runtime DataAccessException.